# Substitute Column With Result of Command

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I'm trying to find a way to quickly and efficiently replace a column value for every row in a file with the output of a command.  I need to work on multiple files with about 500,000 rows each daily so I'm looking for something that can complete the task as quickly as possible.

I need to take the eighth column of a comma delimited row as input, run a command, and replace that column with the output of the command.

This is what I've tried already, and while it works, it is very slow:

```
awk -F "," 'NR > 1 {
    cmd = "cdrtoip " $8
    cmd | getline ip
    close(cmd)
    $8=ip
    print
}' $1.csv >> $1.csv.tmp
```

I would prefer to stick to Bash or other Linux programs that can be found preinstalled on a Linux server.

EDIT: My apologies, I should've included what cdrtoip is.

```
# Convert CISCO format (signed integer) to Hex
# Capitalize or else conversion from hex to decimal doesn't work later
HEXIP=$(printf '%x\n' $1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')

# Negative numbers will get 8 'f' in front of them
# Trim that part off
if [[ ${#HEXIP} -eq 16 ]]; then
    HEXIP=${HEXIP:8:8}
fi

# Convert hex to decimal, separate into octets, put in order
OCTETS[0]=$(echo "ibase=16; ${HEXIP:6:2}" | bc)
OCTETS[1]=$(echo "ibase=16; ${HEXIP:4:2}" | bc)
OCTETS[2]=$(echo "ibase=16; ${HEXIP:2:2}" | bc)
OCTETS[3]=$(echo "ibase=16; ${HEXIP:0:2}" | bc)

# Print the IP
echo ${OCTETS[0]}.${OCTETS[1]}.${OCTETS[2]}.${OCTETS[3]}
```

Running time on cdrip gives:

```
    0.23s real     0.00s user     0.02s system
```

Comment: How slow if it to run `cdrtoip` 500,000 times?  In other words, is the slowness due to awk or due to cdrtoip?

Comment: what does `cdrtoip` do?  can you easily reimplement it inside your awk script?  avoiding 500,000 calls to an external program has (almost certainly) got to be faster.  if you can't do it in awk, perl may be a good alternative.

Comment: If `cdrtoip` could be modified to read lines of cdr (`$8`) and print lines of ip you could speed it up immensely.  How long does one call to `cdrtoip` take to execute?

Comment: I've added the contents of cdrtoip and also timed it.  It doesn't seem to me that cdrtoip is very slow but I could be wrong of course.

Comment: `cdrtoip` itself is not slow.  What *is* slow is having to execute it 500,000 times. By making `cdrtoip` faster, you can drastically improve the overall execution time, because it improves exponentially. As you can see from one of my examples, running it 5,000 times took over 2 minutes (slower than the script itself than ran it in parallel). Multiply that by 100, and that's what you're looking at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work in any version of `awk` that supports user-defined functions, as well as built-in `sprintf()` and `rshift()` functions.  This includes GNU awk.

I borrowed and adapted the decimal to dotted-quad IP Address algorithm from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025177/how-can-i-convert-a-hex-ip-address-to-dotted-decimal-notation

As mentioned in my comment, rewriting the `cdrtoip` external script as an awk function will avoid having to call an external script over 500,000 times.

```sh
awk -F, '
function cdrtoip(addr) {
  return sprintf ("%d.%d.%d.%d",
           rshift(and(addr,0xff000000),24),
           rshift(and(addr,0x00ff0000),16),
           rshift(and(addr,0x0000ff00),08),
           rshift(and(addr,0x000000ff),00))
};

NR > 1 {
    $8 = cdrtoip($8);
    print
}' "$1.csv" >> "$1.csv.tmp"
```

I ran this on a test file with 500,000 lines, and it completed in under 2 seconds:

```sh
$ wc -l input.csv 
500000 input.csv
$ time ./michael.sh < input.csv > output.csv

real 0m1.956s   user 0m1.935s   sys 0m0.018s
```

Comment: This is faster than Python for me.  I just had to rearrange the rshift lines since they were printing the IP reversed.

Comment: that's odd.  it prints the IPs normally for me.  hmmm, maybe not surprising if the 'cdr' decimal numbers came from a cisco device - they use reversed IPs in a lot of places.

Comment: if you added a small (10 lines or so) sample of input and expected output to your question, could probably fix the cdrtoip function to work with your data.

Comment: I figured it out, no worries.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

I know you said you wanted to stick to native applications, but [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) would allow you to execute separate processes in parallel, which would allow you to run this operation more quickly:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install parallel
awk -F',' '{print $8}' file.csv | parallel -j+0 cdrtoip {}
```

There are numerous ways of invoking `parallel`, but the above method would take the output from the 8th column of the .csv file and execute one `cdrtoip` process per core on your system, on each line simultaneously.  So basically, if you are running 4 cores, you could complete this job in 25% of the time it would normally take to execute.

The plus side of `parallel` is that it keeps track of the output and generates it in order, as if it were only a single job running.

After installing, `man parallel` for more ways of executing (or check out the documentation from the link).  Sorry if this is not what you are looking for, but it has come to the rescue for me numerous times in the past.

**EDIT:** If you want to add the output back into the .csv to replace the 8th column, the example below *will* work, and *has* been tested. It takes about 3.25 minutes to execute on a 5,000 line .csv file on a dual-core Macbook Pro.

**The Setup:**

```
$ cat file.tmp
blah1,blah2,blah3,blah4,blah5,blah6,blah7,1175063050,blah9,blah10,blah11

$ for i in {1..5000}; do cat file.tmp; done > file.csv

$ wc -l < file.csv
5000
```

**The Script (using the `cdrtoip` that you provided):**

```
$ cat csvjob.sh
#!/bin/bash

fragment1="$(cut -d, -f1-7 file.csv | tr ',' "\t")"
fragment2="$(cut -d, -f8 file.csv | parallel -j+0 cdrtoip {})"
fragment3="$(cut -d',' -f9- file.csv | tr ',' "\t")"

paste <(echo "$fragment1") <(echo "$fragment2") <(echo "$fragment3") | sed "s/\t/,/g" > newfile.csv
```

**The Result:**

```
$ time ./csvjob.sh
real    3m23.092s
user    1m22.245s
sys     2m57.794s

$ head -3 newfile.csv
blah1,blah2,blah3,blah4,blah5,blah6,blah7,10.10.10.70,blah9,blah10,blah11
blah1,blah2,blah3,blah4,blah5,blah6,blah7,10.10.10.70,blah9,blah10,blah11
blah1,blah2,blah3,blah4,blah5,blah6,blah7,10.10.10.70,blah9,blah10,blah11
```

**Another Edit:**  The following was executed on a quad-core Mac Mini (also running other stuff):

```
$ time ./csvjob.sh
real    2m12.171s
user    2m59.816s
sys     2m15.787s
```

I also just realized you said 500,000 lines instead of 5,000 lines.  For what it's worth, see the stats below for executing `cdrtoip` 5,000 times consecutively:

```
$ time for i in {1..5000}; do cdrtoip 1175063050; done > /dev/null
real    2m32.487s
user    1m26.537s
sys     1m8.270s
```

**Final Edit:** 
The following was run on a 500,000 line file on a quad-core Mac Mini, which as stated earlier, was already running multiple applications:

```
$ time ./csvjob.sh

real    216m22.780s
user    301m40.694s
sys     239m44.404s
```

*I can totally see what you mean, OP.*

*Even when running in parallel, this takes quite awhile to execute.*

*I see that OP has found a better solution. 126 seconds per file is hard to beat. Again, for what it's worth, below are the stats of running the originally-provided `cdrtoip` with a 500,000 line .csv using `parallel` (which I realize OP is not able to install) on an 8-core Debian VM:*

```
$ time ./csvjob.sh
real    14m7.467s
user    6m3.883s
sys     4m18.556s
```

Comment: the OP wants to replace $8 in file.csv with the output of `cdrtoip $8`.

Comment: Right, that's what this is doing...or are you trying to say he wants to feed it as one big blob instead of going line-by-line?

Comment: Oh I think I see - you're saying I'm missing the part where he wants to re-insert it into the .csv...I have 2% battery and will have to re-visit this tomorrow.  It should be pretty simple.

Comment: I've added the contents of cdrtoip and also timed it. It doesn't seem to me that cdrtoip is very slow but I could be wrong of course.

Comment: I have updated my answer to produce the result I think you are looking to achieve.  It has been tested and takes a little over 3 minutes to execute on a 5,000 line .csv on a dual-core system.  The speed will double each time you double the number of processor cores when using the particular `parallel` command referenced in the script I provided.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  Unfortunately I do not have privileges necessary to install new software on this system.  Very good to know that this exists though so thank you.

Comment: @Michael In that case, I would look at the solution that involves rewriting the `cdrtoip` script itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The solution I went with was to rewrite it in a different language and include cdrtoip as a function.  That way it wasn't getting called as a separate process.  That resulted in a time of about 150 seconds per file.

Answer (score 2):

As John1024 points out, the big suspect for slowness is the calling of the cdrtoip 500,000 times.

EDIT: based in the cdrtoip script provided, the entire implementation is in Python. It is much faster because there is no call to an external script.

I would recommend you look at Python for this. The performance of Python is quite good for this type of task, also, there is an existing module to handle csv files included in the standard python library.

Here is a sample implementation in Python. This sample reads and writes to stdin/stdout like your awk script, but it could easily be modified to open files.  EDIT: cleanup and handle conversion errors better. Provide a summary to stderr at the end of processing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,csv

# Convert CISCO format (signed integer) to Hex
# Based on original cdrtoip script in bash
# Note that a ValueError is raised if conversion cannot be done.
def cdrtoip(addrfield):
  intaddr=int(addrfield)    # ValueError if not a valid int

  # Range-check the integer, make it unsigned
  # If out of range, raise a ValueError
  if intaddr < 0: intaddr=intaddr+0x100000000
  if intaddr < 0: raise ValueError
  if intaddr > 0xffffffff : raise ValueError

  return ".".join( [ str(intaddr >> i & 0xff) for i in (24,16,8,0) ] )

# There are other options, depending on the exact file format
# you want. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
indata=csv.reader(sys.stdin)
outdata=csv.writer(sys.stdout)
header=True
no_convert=0
invalid_row=0
row_converted=0
blank_row=0
for row in indata:
   # Write the first line unchanged...
   if header:
      header=False
   else:
      # Note that columns are numbered from 0
      if len(row) == 0:
         blank_row=blank_row+1
         continue
      elif len(row) > 7:
         try:
            row[7]=cdrtoip(row[7])
            row_converted=row_converted+1
         except ValueError:
            # if conversion fails, we count and leave the field unchanged.
            no_convert=no_convert+1
      else:
         # if there is no column 8 we count as invalid row.
         invalid_row=invalid_row+1

   outdata.writerow(row)

# Print a summary of work done (to stderr).
print >> sys.stderr,"%d values converted." % row_converted
if no_convert > 0:
   print >> sys.stderr,"%d values not converted." % no_convert
if invalid_row > 0:
   print >> sys.stderr,"%d rows not valid." % invalid_row
if blank_row > 0:
   print >> sys.stderr,"%d blank rows removed." % blank_row
```

Comment: If the slowness is due to calling an external command 500,000+ times then it'll make little difference whether cdrtoip is called from shell or awk or python.  Rewriting cdrtoip as an awk or python or perl etc function, however, could speed it up enormously.

Comment: The questioner has a working solution and is asking about performance.  Do you have evidence that this will improve the performance?  I agree with others that the bottleneck is starting 500,000 processes, this python script still does that.

Comment: I've added the contents of cdrtoip and also timed it. It doesn't seem to me that cdrtoip is very slow but I could be wrong of course.

Comment: The version of Python available to me is 2.3.4 so I do not have access to the subprocess module.  Will rewriting the program without that module significantly affect performance?

Comment: By doing it all in python, you don't need subprocess. I updated the Python example based on your cdrtoip bash script.

Comment: ".".join( [ str(intaddr >> i & 0xff) for i in (24,16,8,0) ] ) works (note 0, not 1).

Comment: In your "Range Checking", the original script does only a bitwise and `&` with 0xffffffff (`HEXIP=${HEXIP:8:8}`), you do a different process which appears to return a different value than the original. Why?

Comment: This is because the bash printf '%x\n' is sign-extending to 64 bits. Really, the script would work without the range-check or sign conversion, but I felt it was more valid to leave out-of-range values as-is to avoid loosing any information.

Comment: I like this answer. I constructively offer my opinions: Proselytizing python doesn't help your technical position.  The words "every, easy, forgiving, convenient", etc are opinion and should be self-evident in the answer. For this site, the code is comment-heavy.  The comments obscure the simplicity and elegance of the code and make it appear longer and more complicated than in reality, and also more difficult to follow.  This is only my opinion, take it if you need it, if you don't then pass it on.

Comment: More in my humble opinion for readability: Stylistically, I would remove the original shell code, and put the first three initialization statements, with no comments, just above the `for` loop.  Annotate things like the `csv` module and standard io in you text description outside the code block.  I have reservations about putting the wrong data type into the output file and would rather see an exception or warning message in that case.  That's great code and a great answer to this question. Thank you for submitting this answer and answering my questions.

Answer (score 2):

`cdrtoip` is indeed pretty slow, it looks like a useful utility script but was probably not intended to be called hundreds of times in a loop. I'm assuming it's a common tool that is used by other scripts or users, and you want to keep using it but make it faster.

Just making one call to `bc` instead of 4 makes the script run in about 1/3 the time. Using shell conversions instead of `bc` can make the script run in about 1/5 the time.

I made a short framework to generate a bunch of sample input (about 500 lines) and then run two scripts, `orig.sh` (the original `cdrtoip`) and `new.sh`, a modified version, and time them and compare their outputs. It looks like:

```
INPUT_SIZE=500
SAMPLE_FILE=in.txt

rm -f $SAMPLE_FILE orig.out new.out

x=0
while [[ $((x++)) -le $INPUT_SIZE ]]; do
    tr -cd '[:digit:]' < /dev/urandom | head -c 10 | sed s/^0/1/ >> $SAMPLE_FILE
    echo >> $SAMPLE_FILE
    if [[ $((x%10)) -eq 0 ]]; then echo -n .; fi
    if [[ $((x%20)) -eq 0 ]]; then echo -n '-' >> $SAMPLE_FILE; fi # next num is negative
done
echo

echo new cdrtoip:
time while read line; do ./new.sh $line >> new.out; done < $SAMPLE_FILE

echo original cdrtoip:
time while read line; do ./orig.sh $line >> orig.out; done < $SAMPLE_FILE

diff -q orig.out new.out || echo "Output was different!"
```

The output with one `bc` call:

```
$ ./generate.sh 
..................................................
new cdrtoip:

real    0m1.431s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.072s
original cdrtoip:

real    0m4.381s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.084s
```

Here's my `new.sh`. If you want the faster version, comment out the `bc` line and uncomment out the conversions below it (about 0.85 seconds), and you can also get rid of the `${HEXIP^^}` capitalization. If you keep `${HEXIP^^}` you should probably include a `bash` shebang because it won't work in all shells (it will, notably, fail in dash).

```
#!/bin/bash
# Convert CISCO format (signed integer) to Hex
# Capitalize or else conversion from hex to decimal doesn't work later
HEXIP=$(printf '%x' $1)
HEXIP=${HEXIP^^}

# Negative numbers will get 8 'f' in front of them
# Trim that part off
if [[ ${#HEXIP} -eq 16 ]]; then
    HEXIP=${HEXIP:8:8}
fi

# Convert hex to decimal, separate into octets, put in order
bc <<< "ibase=16; ${HEXIP:6:2}; ${HEXIP:4:2}; ${HEXIP:2:2}; ${HEXIP:0:2}" | tr '\n' . | sed 's/[\.]$/\n/'

# Convert hex to decimal, separate into octets, put in order
# using just bash: doesn't require hex characters to be upper case
#o0=$((16#${HEXIP:6:2}))
#o1=$((16#${HEXIP:4:2}))
#o2=$((16#${HEXIP:2:2}))
#o3=$((16#${HEXIP:0:2}))

# Print the IP
#echo $o0.$o1.$o2.$o3
```

Comment: Thanks, the way you rewrote the cdrtoip script is indeed much faster.